# Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

Due to this line in my codes :

```
var myRef = child_myRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid)
```

[image: Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expecte]

Comment: Are you using Java 10?  If so, please add that tag to your question.

Comment: @Tim looks like Kotlin

Comment: `child_myRef.child` expects a string, but `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid` could be null... That's what the message is saying

Comment: No, its Java 8 @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @EmmanuelJohnHilonga what excatly are you trying in that line FirebaseAuth.getInstance.uid???

Comment: can you atleast post your sample structure so everyone can help you out

Answer (score 2):

The reason because your `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid` is `String?` (can be Null), but input of `.child()` need a `String` (none Null), so please check null before that:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid?.let{
  var myRef = child_myRef.child(it) 
  .....
}
```

Or if you make sure `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid` never Null, you can using `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid!!`, but It not is a good approach

Answer (score 0):

You can replace it with `child_myRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid!!)` or check for `null`.

Comment: he is trying to create a child reference  based  upon userid

Comment: This one works perfect. Now authenticated users can post data into realtime database with their respective ID's. This line child_myRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid!!) solve my problem completely. Thanks @Bek

Comment: `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid!!` may return `NullPointerException` use GianhTran's answer to avoid exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myRef = child_myRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
myRef.child("jina").setValue(Fname.text.toString())
myRef.child("tarehe").setValue(bDate.text.toString())
myRef.child("place").setValue(place.text.toString())
```

Hope you are trying to put all the details under user id.
So if thats the case kindly change your reference to myRef.
So you can put it under your user id all the above details.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the value of `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid` can be `null` , so first check if its not null , then perform your operation .

```
if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid!=null){
var myRef = child_myRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid)
myRef.child("jina").setValue(Fname.text.toString())
myRef.child("tarehe").setValue(bDate.text.toString())
myRef.child("place").setValue(place.text.toString())

}
```

> If you check with `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid!!` this will cause a
>   `Null Pointer Exception` and your app will crash if
>   `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid` value comes as `null`, so try the
>   above approach (as i wrote sample)

Answer (score 0):

[This line works : child_myRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid!!) and now it is good.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r120m.png)

[My codes now are like the second image. Thak you all for your help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw541.png)